# Como ordenar un arreglo de String con datos numericos

Tags: java

hace tiempo tengo esta duda el cual dice, como puedo comparar varios String respetando los datos numéricos que puedan contener como en el re-nombramiento de archivos de una carpeta cualquiera. Estuve investigando, y razón  la cual al comparar los String con este tipo de datos resulta diferente a lo que uno espera, se debe a que se ordenan de forma lexicografica (Caracter por caracter) pero aun así no hallo una forma de resolverlo.

Ademas quiero decir que no puedo simplemente quietar todos los caracteres que no sean numeros y ordenarlos, porque en los String que estoy usando pueden tener números por medio.

Este es un ejemplo de mi problema

```
String[] nombres = {"hola 1", "hola 5", "hola 15", "hola 2};

    //Ordena el array
    Arrays.sort(nombres);

    //Array ya ordenado
    for (String i : nombres) {
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    }
```

El resultado que obtengo es:

> hola 1, hola 15, hola 2, hola 5

El resultado que yo quiero es:

> hola 1, hola 2, hola 5, hola 15

Me gustaria saber si existe un metodo para resolver mi problema.

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que has intentado :)

Comment: Ya he añadido un ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @GetsugaTenshou de esta forma es más entendible y atractiva tu pregunta, y puedes tener muy buenas respuestas, no olvides revisar [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria algo así:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.Collections;

    public class MyClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("hola 1", "hola 5", "hola 15", "hola 2");
     Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2);
        }

        int extractInt(String s) {
            String num = s.replaceAll("\\D", "");
            return num.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(num);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(strings);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[hola 1, hola 2, hola 5, hola 15]

Fuente: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973503/sorting-strings-that-contains-number-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que crear un comparador personalizado, aquí te dejo uno: http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java

Una vez que lo tengas en tu proyecto, solo tienes que usarlo así:

```
Arrays.sort(nombres, new AlphanumComparator());
```

La salida para tu ejemplo es la siguiente:

> hola 1, hola 2, hola 5, hola 15,

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el resultado que obtienes al ordenar el array original mediante:

```
Arrays.sort(nombres);
```

es

> hola 1, hola 15, hola 2, hola 5

Porque esta ordenando en realidad un String, en este caso trata de ordenar los que inician con hola 1, (hola 1, hola 15), y así sucesivamente:

Por ejemplo si tuvieras como array:

```
String[] nombres = {"hola 1", "hola 3", "hola 5", "hola 15", "hola 2","hola 1222", "hola 1999"};
```

Se ordenaría de esta forma:

> hola 1, hola 1222, hola 15, hola 1999, hola 2, hola 3, hola 5

Se tiene que realizar el ordenamiento de los caracteres como si fueran números enteros.

---

Este sería un método usando una clase que implementa Comparator, esta sería la clase:

```
    static class ColumnComparator implements Comparator {
    int columnToSort;
    ColumnComparator(int columnToSort) {
        this.columnToSort = columnToSort;
    }
    //sobreescribe metodo compare
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String[] row1 = (String[]) o1;
        String[] row2 = (String[]) o2;

                int res = Integer.parseInt(row1[0].toString()) -  Integer.parseInt(row2[0].toString());         
                return res;
    }
}
```

Y realizarías el ordenamiento de esta forma:

```
        String[] nombres = {"hola 1", "hola 5", "hola 15", "hola 2"};    

        String[][] nombresAOrdenar = new String[nombres.length][2]; 

        for (int i=0; i< nombres.length ; i++) {
            //Extrae valores de array, el numero será la columna a ordenar.
            String[] parts = nombres[i].split(" ");
            nombresAOrdenar[i][0] =  parts[1];
            nombresAOrdenar[i][1] =  parts[0];        
        }  

        //Ordena valores por columna 1 (indice 0)
        Arrays.sort(nombresAOrdenar, new ColumnComparator(0));

       //Agrega valores ordenados a array original 
       for (int j=0; j< nombres.length ; j++) {           
            nombres[j] = nombresAOrdenar[j][1].toString() + " "+ nombresAOrdenar[j][0].toString();
       }
```

Al tener ordenado el array ahora puedes imprimir los valores:

```
   //Imprime valores de Array ya ordenado
   for (String nombre : nombres) {
        System.out.print(nombre + ", ");
   }
```

Para tener como salida:

```
hola 1, hola 2, hola 5, hola 15
```

---

Esta es una [**demo online**](https://www.ideone.com/DbEF2I) de lo anterior.