# Listar archivos de un directorio en Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo este código con el que estoy listando los archivos .sql que hay en un directorio, en concreto 20 archivos cuyo nombre es su numero. Cuando el programa lista los archivos lo hace de la siguiente manera (debajo código). Como puedo hacer para que lo haga en orden ascendente y no así?

```
public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escribe la ruta: ");
    String ruta = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Escribe la extension: ");
    String ext = sc.nextLine();
    File carpeta = new File(ruta);
    File[] archivos;
    if(carpeta.exists()) {
        if(carpeta.isDirectory()) {
            archivos = carpeta.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<archivos.length; i++) {
                if(archivos[i].getName().endsWith(ext)) 
                    System.out.println(archivos[i].getName());
            }
        }
    }

Escribe la ruta: 
C:\Users\SAG\Desktop\Sql\CarpetaSQL
Escribe la extension: 
sql
1.sql
10.sql
11.sql
12.sql
13.sql
14.sql
15.sql
16.sql
17.sql
18.sql
19.sql
2.sql
20.sql
3.sql
4.sql
5.sql
6.sql
7.sql
8.sql
9.sql
```

Comment: [Esta entrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136916/como-ordenar-un-arreglo-de-string-con-datos-numericos) te puede ayudar

Answer (score 1):

esta pregunta es un poco Vieja pero me gustaria ejemplificar otra forma Utilizando Clases mas Modernas (de java 8+ y lambda) mediante el [paquete `java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-frame.html) 
y listando archivos mediante el uso de [DirectoryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#listdir)

NOTA:

esta solucion trata de ser lo mas simple possible. y unicamente "ordenara los archivos que su nombre sea numeros" si el nombre de este no son numeros se listara al final de la lista Ordenados por "Natural Ordering". Para aplicar un ordenamiento mas "refinado" se debe crear un `java.util.Comparator` y utilizar `files.sort(<El Comparator creado>)` tal y como se define en la otra respuesta.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class orderFileList {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe la ruta: ");
        String ruta = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Escribe la extension: ");
        String ext = sc.nextLine();
        Path dir = Paths.get(ruta);
        if (Files.exists(dir, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS) && Files.isDirectory(dir, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
            try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, String.format("*.%s", ext))) {
                ArrayList<Path> files = new ArrayList<>();
                stream.forEach(files::add);
                //utilize un natural order primero para ordenar por nombre
                files.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
                //utilize nuestro ordernado por Numero.
                files.sort(Comparator.comparing(file -> getnumeric(file),Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
                files.forEach( file -> System.out.println(file.getFileName().toString()));
            }
        }
    }

    private static Integer getnumeric(Path file) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(file.getFileName().toString().substring(0, file.getFileName().toString().indexOf('.')));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

resultado de un ejemplo:

```
Escribe la ruta: 
C:\Users\silencio\Desktop\test
Escribe la extension: 
sql
1.sql
2.sql
3.sql
4.sql
5.sql
6.sql
7.sql
8.sql
9.sql
10.sql
11.sql
12.sql
13.sql
14.sql
15.sql
16.sql
17.sql
18.sql
19.sql
20.sql
ad.sql
ed.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que tienes que hacer es pasarle al metodo sort() del Array  un comparador personalizado. en este caso `AlphanumFileComparator` y de esa forma tu código tendría que quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe la ruta: ");
        String ruta = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Escribe la extension: ");
        String ext = sc.nextLine();
        File carpeta = new File(ruta);
        FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*." + ext);
        if (carpeta.exists()) {
            if (carpeta.isDirectory()) {
                File[] archivos = carpeta.listFiles(fileFilter);
                Arrays.sort(archivos, new AlphanumFileComparator());
                for (int i = 0; i < archivos.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(archivos[i].getName());

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el código del Comparador:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class AlphanumFileComparator implements Comparator {

    private final boolean isDigit(char ch) {
        return ch >= 48 && ch <= 57;
    }


    private final String getChunk(String s, int slength, int marker) {
        StringBuilder chunk = new StringBuilder();
        char c = s.charAt(marker);
        chunk.append(c);
        marker++;
        if (isDigit(c)) {
            while (marker < slength) {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (!isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        } else {
            while (marker < slength) {
                c = s.charAt(marker);
                if (isDigit(c))
                    break;
                chunk.append(c);
                marker++;
            }
        }
        return chunk.toString();
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (!(o1 instanceof File) || !(o2 instanceof File)) {
            return 0;
        }
        File f1 = (File) o1;
        File f2 = (File) o2;
        String s1 = f1.getName();
        String s2 = f2.getName();

        int thisMarker = 0;
        int thatMarker = 0;
        int s1Length = s1.length();
        int s2Length = s2.length();

        while (thisMarker < s1Length && thatMarker < s2Length) {
            String thisChunk = getChunk(s1, s1Length, thisMarker);
            thisMarker += thisChunk.length();

            String thatChunk = getChunk(s2, s2Length, thatMarker);
            thatMarker += thatChunk.length();

            /** If both chunks contain numeric characters, sort them numerically **/

            int result = 0;
            if (isDigit(thisChunk.charAt(0)) && isDigit(thatChunk.charAt(0))) {
                // Simple chunk comparison by length.
                int thisChunkLength = thisChunk.length();
                result = thisChunkLength - thatChunk.length();
                // If equal, the first different number counts
                if (result == 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < thisChunkLength; i++) {
                        result = thisChunk.charAt(i) - thatChunk.charAt(i);
                        if (result != 0) {
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                result = thisChunk.compareTo(thatChunk);
            }

            if (result != 0)
                return result;
        }
        return s1Length - s2Length;
    }
}
```

De esa forma tu resultado sera algo como:

```
Escribe la ruta: 
/home/efren/Archivos
Escribe la extension: 
sql
1.sql
2.sql
3.sql
4.sql
5.sql
6.sql
7.sql
8.sql
9.sql
10.sql
11.sql
12.sql
13.sql

Process finished with exit code 0
```